# How to read the info format of the GNU Standard C Library?

Tags: debian, man, info

I have installed the glibc-doc-reference package in Debian Bullseye, and the [package documentation](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/glibc-doc-reference) says that it Contains The GNU C Library Reference manual in info, pdf and html format. The HTML format is easy enough to open, and the PDF file is possible to extract from the compressed file. But I would like to try to read the info format in the terminal. I thought it could be possible to read these from the info reader, but how? What is the recommended way of opening these files? They are 14 gz-files stored as e.g. /usr/share/info/libc.info.gz and I have no clue what to do with them, but I want to learn. Should I extract them to my home directory, one by one?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this command:

```
info libc
```

Or, also, but actually from some other package `info glibc`.

You could list all possible info entries (for libc) with:

```
info -k libc
```

And then use one of the entries:

```
info "(libc)Memory Allocation Tunables"
```

For the `malloc` section of the info book.

Or, if you so wish, read a file directly:

```
info /usr/share/info/libc.info-10.gz
```